# scikit decision tree and splits for categorical variables

Tags: authentication, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ordinal

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn import preprocessing
import os
import subprocess

def categorical_split():
    colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']
    sizes = ['small', 'large', 'medium', 'large', 'small']

    size_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    sizes = size_encoder.fit_transform(sizes).reshape(-1, 1)

    color_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    colors = size_encoder.fit_transform(colors).reshape(-1, 1)

    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier( random_state=99)
    dt.fit(colors, sizes)

    with open("dt.dot", 'w') as f:
        export_graphviz(dt, out_file=f,
                        feature_names='colors')

    command = ["dot", "-Tpng", "dt.dot", "-o", "dt.png"]
    subprocess.check_call(command)

categorical_split()
```

It generates the following decision tree:[image]

Since decision tree in scikit-learn can not handle categorical variables directly, I had to use LabelEncoder. On the graph we see splits like `c<=1.5`. This kind of split indicates that categorical variables are treated like ordinal variable and split is preserving order. If my data does not have order this kind approach is detrimental. Is there way around it? If you are planning to suggest one-hot encoding, could you please provide an example(code) how it is going to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a perfectly valid approach, and shouldn't be detrimental to your model performance. It does make the model a little hard to read though. One nice approach is to use `pd.get_dummies` since this will take care of the model names for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'colors':colors})
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df)
dt.fit(df_encoded, sizes)

with open("dt.dot", 'w') as f:
    export_graphviz(dt, out_file=f,
                    feature_names=df_encoded.columns)

command = ["dot", "-Tpng", "dt.dot", "-o", "dt.png"]
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you agree with my guess that scikit-learn treats categorical variables as ordinal and preserves order while constructing the tree?

Comment: I meant to say preserves order while choosing split for the tree.

Comment: perhaps, i guess my point is that any categorical value can be isolated on its own by a pair of inequalities. you won't get groupings of your categorical variables, so your tree will have more leaves than you would need with grouping but you don't get this with one-hot-encoding either ... it's just an unfortunate weakness of the fact that scikit learn doesn't treat categorical variables properly

Comment: I would like to construct an example with expression like `1.5<=c<=2.5`. Let me work on it.